# how can I set value to an item in list SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a radio Item SharePoint and radio button in HTML code.
what I need It's: when I check on radio buton,the radio Item will be checked :
If I check "yes", the "yes" of SharePoint item will be cheked, and the reverse.
So,how can I set the value to the SharePoint item without c# coding?

this is the html code:

```
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader">                              
        <nobr>Lien avec courrier antérieur* </nobr>                     
    </H3>                       
</td>       
<td>
    <input type= "radio" id ="b" name="radstate"></input>yes
    <input type= "radio" id ="a" name="radstate" checked="checked"></input>No<br/>
</td>
```

this is the xsl code:

```
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Lien avec courrier antérieur</nobr>
    </H3>
</td>
<td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
    <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff11{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Lien_x0020_avec_x0020_courrier_x" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff11',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Lien_x0020_avec_x0020_courrier_x')}"/>
    <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff11description{$Pos}" FieldName="Lien_x0020_avec_x0020_courrier_x" ControlMode="New"/>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery or JavaScript. Use following code block to capture the checked event

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    jQuery("input[name='radstate']").change(radioValueChanged);
})

function radioValueChanged()
{
    radioId = jQuery(this).attr('id');

    if(jQuery(this).is(":checked") && radioId == "a")
    {
        UpdateListValue(true);
    }
    else if(jQuery(this).is(":checked") && radioId == "b")
    {
        UpdateListValue(false);
    }
}
```

Now we need to use SharePoint JavaScript Object Model to save information back to the list

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function updateListItem() {
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('LISTNAME');

this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(ITEMID); //Number

oListItem.set_item('FieldInternalName', NEWVALUE);
oListItem.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

More on JSOM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: With javascript Object Model, I must use visual studio.is there another way to do it without visual studio, may be with sharepoint designer ? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You can use any text editor and then copy the code into a Content Editor webpart.